# JMSMessageProducer_A JMSException The JMS connection has failed: java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I am having Oracle SOA integration which is connecting to ActiveMQ broker using JMS adapter.
In this we are producing events on topic. For this integration we are receiving below error sometimes very infrequently.

```
JMSMessageProducer_A JMSException was caught: org.apache.activemq.ConnectionFailedException: The JMS connection has failed: java.io.EOFException The JMS connection has failed: java.io.EOFException. closeCCIConnection: [default destination = location-inbound] Destroying Application Connection Handle and invalidating pool...
```

I am reading ActiveMQ documentation to find root cause and probable solution for it.
Any help to move further is appreciated. Thanks in advance.